# When use hibernate search, how to use Analyzer which doesn't have no-argument constructor

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

[image: Screenshot]

how to use an Analyzer with constructor which need a argument?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Search will look for, in order:

- a public constructor which takes one parameter of type `org.apache.lucene.util.Version` (as this is a common requiremnt).
- a public no-arguments constructor

So if your custom analyzer just needs the `Version` that will work out of the box and there's no need to make changes to it.

For other needs, you will have to add a no-argument constructor to your Analyzer.

If you can't change the source code of the Analyzer, a common solution is to subclass it, and add a no-arguments constructor. You will likely have to invoke the parent constructor and pass it some constants.